# If Reader Read on Sitemaster

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, cookies, authentication

Well, Im trying to do a login on sitemaster, It works fine.. but on Login i want a label to have something stored.. and  something disappear

This is my sitemaster code..

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="headerwrap">
            <div class="logo"><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>"><img width="70%" height="85%" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/hiremelogo.png") %>" /></a></div>
            <div id="container">
            <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx?logout=1") %>"><div class="logout" id="logout" runat="server"><div class ="text">Logout</div></div></a>

            <!-- Login Starts Here -->
            <div runat="server" id="loginContainer">
                <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>Login</span><em></em></a>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div id="loginBox">        
                <div class="loginForm">        
                    <form id="loginForm">
                        <fieldset id="body" class="bodyy">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="email">Username</label>
                                <asp:TextBox name="email" id="email" type="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <asp:TextBox type="password" name="password" id="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </fieldset>
                            <asp:Button id="login" class="loginbutton" runat="server" Text="Sign in" onclick="login_Click" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Login Ends Here -->
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
        <div id="div2" runat="server"></div>
        <div id="div3" runat="server"></div>

        <div class="menuwrap">
        <div class="menu_simple">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seekers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>



            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>


        <div class="breakline"></div>

        <div class="footerwrap">
        <div id="asdasd" runat="server"></div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class hireme : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["logout"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["admin1"] = "";
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["admin2"] = "";
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["username"] = "";
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["username1"] = "";
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["sid"] = "";
            Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["eid"] = "";
            Response.Redirect(Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"].ToString());
        }

    }
    protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (USER(email.Text).Equals(true))
        {
            SqlConnection myConn, myConn2;
            SqlCommand myCommand, myCommand2;
            SqlDataReader myReader, myReader2;
            String SQL, SQL2;
            myConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            myConn2 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());

            myConn.Open();
            myConn2.Open();
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM seekers WHERE s_username = @user AND s_password = @pass";
            SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM employers WHERE e_username = @user AND e_password = @pass";
            myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, myConn);
            myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, myConn2);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", email.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password.Text);
            myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", email.Text);
            myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password.Text);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();


            if (myReader.Read())
            {

                div1.InnerText = "Login Success!";
                Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["username"] = email.Text;
                Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["sid"] = myReader["s_id"].ToString();
                Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["eid"] = "0";
                logout.Visible = false;
                Label1.Text = "TEST";
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");


            }
            else
            {
                asdasd.InnerText = "S Fail";
                div1.Visible = true;
                div2.Visible = false;
                div3.Visible = false;
                div1.InnerHtml = "<br><div class='alert alert-error'>Invalid Username/Password!</div>";
            }



            myConn.Close();


        }
        else
        {
            asdasd.InnerText = "Full Fail";
            div1.Visible = true;
            div2.Visible = false;
            div3.Visible = false;
            div1.InnerHtml = "<br><div class='alert alert-error'>You are not Registered! Please Register first to use the Service</div>";
        }

    }

    public Boolean USER(String username)
    {
        SqlConnection myConn;
        SqlCommand myCommand;
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        String SQL;
        myConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());

        myConn.Open();
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM seekers WHERE s_username = @user";
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, myConn);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", email.Text);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (myReader.Read())
        {
            myConn.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            myConn.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Well, the login works fine, i can retrieve cookies value on my default page, the problem is Label1 does not update and logout is still visible..

Im not sure what im doing wrong here..

Any help would be possible...!

Answer (score 1):

Your login procedure ends with a redirect to another page:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Setting values on the current page, won't do anything. The browser will just redirect to the default page.

The solution would be to check on the load of the Default page whether the user is logged in and react to that by showing the correct panels.

Comment: So thats the reason its not working, Well when i try to request.Cookies[UserSettings] to decide if he or she logged in, it works... but if i clear all browser cookies and then load default page, error comes up about nullreference

Comment: Test if the cookie is null first, if it's null, then the user is not logged in.

Comment: Im using this on default page load function.
`if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["username"] != null)`
It works fine when logged in, but when there is no cookie its giving null error

Comment: You need to test for `if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)` first.

Comment: That seems to make it work? but what i want is like an adminbar to popup if user login... That means i need the code to be in sitemaster right?

Comment: Yes. The admin panel needs to be added to your aspx.

Comment: I mean if admin bar is needed to be put on sitemaster, then i need to remove response redirect right?